# Can I be Vulnerable To XSS In 6 Characters

Tags: php, xss

So what I've been trying do is have users be able **to pick their background color**, in the HTML color code format.

Then I will custom have their page use the background color they specified. But I'm having trouble with one little problem. I cannot HTML special chars the color code format they select, because then the HTML wont read it. But I don't want them to be able to XSS my site because of this. What should I do to fix this? How should I get around this?

Comment: take a look at this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30431/minimum-size-of-input-text-box-required-for-xss-attacks

Comment: *I cannot HTML special chars the color code format they select, because then the HTML wont read it.*

There is no means in HTML or CSS to represent a colour that would use any of the characters that PHP's `htmlspecialchars()` function modifies, so that seems very unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

If your users can chose a HEX code you have to check the input you get back if that is a valid hex value.

So you have to check if it has a length of 6 characters and if all characters are valid hexadecimal numbers (0-f). You could use [ctype_xdigit](http://php.net/ctype_xdigit) to do this. All other input values have to be rejected and you could then pass a default hex value to you coloring function as a background color.

I can't see why you should need html special chars if you just can validate your input data.

Edit: And yes you could be vulnerable to XSS with 6 characters. The length doesn't matter here.